# JPA Save Data will try to Update Lazy Field when ID Exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am very frustrated at the moment. I spend hours of hours to get JPA + Hibernate work.

My Problem is - I have this Entity:

```
@Entity
public class APPUser implements UserDetails{
    
    @Id
    private String username;
    
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private Date geburtstag;
    private String email;
    private int locked;
    private String passwort;
    private String passwortresetkey;
    private Timestamp passwortresettimestamp;
    private String lastloginip;
    
    /*@ElementCollection(targetClass = APPUserRoles.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable( 
            name = "appuserroles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
        )
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)*/
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private List<APPUserroles> appuserroles;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<APPToken> tokens;
```

How you see i have `private List<APPUserroles> appuserroles;` defined as LAZY.

Now i call the Save Method from Respository to Save a new User (Insert):

```
public void saveNewUserinDatabase(RegisterRequest request) {
        String remoteAddr = "";

        APPUser appuser = new APPUser(
                request.getUsername(),
                request.getVorname(),
                request.getNachname(),
                request.getGeburtstag(),
                request.getEmail(),
                request.getLocked(),
                passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPasswort()),
                "",
                remoteAddr
        );
        userRepository.save(appuser);
    }
```

so this is easy ...

In the Constructor i dont pass any appuserroles so it is null.

WHEN i try to save a user with a new username so all is working fine

BUT when i try to save (insert) a user with a username which exists in Database so JPA/Hibernate will try to UPDATE the APPUserRoles Table in Database - BUT WHY? How can i get Hibernate to ONLY SAVE the User table? and dont try to Update the AppUserRoles table?

This is the Error i get:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert NULL value into username column, SLAPPS.dbo.APPUserRoles table. The column does not allow NULL values. UPDATE failed.
```

i also see he try to update the Column:

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        appuserroles 
    set
        username=null 
    where
        username=?
```

The AppUserRoles class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class APPUserroles {
    
    @Id
    private String username;
    
    private String rolename;
}
```

**is realy the only Solution to make a own Query in JPARepository With an Insert Statement??**

Comment: can you show AppUserRoles class

Comment: i post the AppUserRoles class in my Question

Comment: *"BUT when i try to save (insert) a user with a username which exists in Database"* - The username is the ID in your entity, so if you have an entity with that ID set and the ID exists in the database, it is no more than logical that Hibernate/JPA will treat it as an update of an existing record instead of an insert.

Comment: The issue is you are passing in an instance that represents data already in the database. If you want to maintain the integrity of the appuserroles without having to pass them into the request, you must read in the APPUser and merge in the changes you want to make to it yourself - JPA cannot decide that it should ignore the null appuserroles when that is a perfectly valid state for the appuserroles collection, and means something. Other answers should already have explained that the FK/ID of APPUserroles is controlled by this unidirectional 1:M mapping which may not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the cascade attribute in the @OneToMany annotation? I think that, if you need to keep these entities stricty tied with che user, you need to inform the jpa mapping that every operation is done to the "parent" (i.e. the user) needs to be propagated to the children (i.e. the roles).

Try setting:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
```

Or, at most:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

To cover all cases.

Comment: sorry i dont understand your answer. I want to Insert a User in Database but Hibernate try to Update the column username on APPUserRoles with NULL. I dont understand WHY? and how i can save ONLY in APPUser Table (He Should ignore the Relations) ... It works fine when i try this with a non exist username.

Comment: He can not ignore the relations as your username is the `@Id` field in both and further the foreign key for your list. Could you show us how you perform the update of an existing AppUser entity? I assume that you are not fetching the existing entity before updating. Therefore the updated entity has an empty appuserroles list which forces hibernate to NULL the existing relations.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is that you are having AppUserRole.userName as both **primary key** and **foreign key**. why is this a problem? from [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many:%7E:text=when%20managing%20the%20collection%20persistence%20state.%20Every%20element%20removal%20only%20requires%20a%20single%20update%20(in%20which%20the%20foreign%20key%20column%20is%20set%20to%20NULL))

> when managing the collection(roles list) persistence state. Every element(role) removal only requires a single update (in which the foreign key column(AppUserRoles.userName) is set to NULL)

so for hibernate to update appUser removing roles "setting roles List to null" it breaks the relationship by setting the foreign key of the roles table to null which happens to be also the primary key and primary keys do not accept null.

**SOLUTION**:
do not make username the primary key of role table.

**NOTE**: if you have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` you may need to update the primaryKey directly from Mysql workbench